# Showing $\binom{n}{1}-2\binom{n}{2}+3\binom{n}{3}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n\binom{n}{n}=0$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$$\binom{n}{1}-2\binom{n}{2}+3\binom{n}{3}+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}n\binom{n}{n}=0$$

I tried solving this identity using this one:
$$(n+1) \cdot C(n,k) = (k+1) \cdot C(n+1,k+1)$$
but I didn't get any far.

Any hints for the solution would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582239/how-to-prove-this-result-on-binomial-coefficients?noredirect=1) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are familiar with differentiation, expand $(1-x)^n$ using binomial theorem and then differentiate, finally substitute $1$ in the expression.

We can do like this $$(1-x)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} C(n,k) (-1)^k x^k$$

Now differentiating both sides, $$-n (1-x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k= 1}^{n} kC(n,k) (-1)^k x^{k-1}$$ and substitute $1$

Answer (score 1):

By binomial identity
\begin{align}
(1 - x)^n = 1 - \binom{n}{1}x + \binom{n}{2}x^2 + \cdots + (-1)^n\binom{n}{n}x^n. 
\end{align}
Taking derivative with respect to $x$ on both sides yields
\begin{align*}
n(1 - x)^{n - 1}(-1) = -\binom{n}{1} + 2\binom{n}{2}x + \cdots + (-1)^nn\binom{n}{n}x^{n - 1}.
\end{align*}
Setting $x = 1$ on the above equation then gives the desired result.